# Ajuda em consulta SQL ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle, pl-sql

[image: Tabela no banco de dados oracle]

Coluna DEPENDENCIA: T - Titular; E - Esposa; F - Filhos; FA - Filho Adotivo

Conforme tabela acima, como faço para trazer os dados somente dos CEP´S que estão divergentes como o CEP do Titular:

> O Titular Admilson tem 2 filhos com o cep diferente, assim como o
> titular Marcelo.

Abusando um pouco mais, é possível trazer os dados do titular e logo abaixo os dados dos filhos com os ceps divergentes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode fazer assim:

```
select
    tabela.familia as familia_titular,
    nao_titular.familia as familia_nao_titular,
    tabela.nome,
    nao_titular.nome,
    nao_titular.cep
from
    tabela,
    (
        select 
            familia,
            cep
        from 
            tabela 
        where
            dependencia <> 'T'
    ) as nao_titular
where
    tabela.familia = nao_titular.familia
    and tabela.dependencia = 'T'
    and tabela.cep <> nao_titular.cep;
```

Comment: Igor, obrigado pela ajuda, mas este select trouxe 5 registros iguais de cada titular, não trazendo o titular e os dependentes com ceps divergentes.

Comment: Acho que é só trocar as colunas do select. Editei a resposta. Veja se agora funciona.

Comment: Igor, fiz isso mas está trazendo dados de titulares que não pertencem a familia.

Comment: Editei a resposta novamente. Poderia postar (comentário) o resultado da SQL?

Comment: Igor, deu certo, muito obrigado, eu coloquei um filtro nos registros que estavam desativados e o select funcionou perfeito. Valeu!!

Comment: Legal cara! Fico feliz por ter ajudado. Se achar que resposta solucionou o problema poderia marcar como solução, por favor?

Comment: Claro, marcado e mais uma vez, muito obrigado.